Fix unwanted squash commit in git branch
I have two branches, called "main" and "release":
main:
release:

Both branches are identical (same commits, same tags) till commit A:
main:    (...) - A
release: (...) - A

I did some commits to "main" (called B, C and D), and I intended to do a MR from "main" to "release", so release got those same changes. But I squashed those commits by accident. So release has now a "S" commit, which is the squash of B, C and D
main:    (...) - A-B-C-D
release: (...) - A-S

Problem is that, if I make now more commits to "main" release (i.e: E, F and G), and then try to do a MR to "release" again, the MR "explodes": it complains about collisions, ask me to do a rebase first (talking about GitLab UI), etc.
main:    (...) - A-B-C-D-E-F-G
release: (...) - A-S ??? -E-F-G ???

And that is not what I want to do (I'm working in a permissions-restricted environment, so I don't have full control over the repo).
I can fix this easily by doing, on release branch, a "git rebase", dropping the "S" commit. That will leave "release" branch clean, and then I can to a MR from main to release with all the commits. But this approach my be rejected (due to "rebase" not being liked too much).
Is there a way to make "release" and "main" branches similar again, FROM commit A, without going to rebases or hard resets? Note that before commit A, there are tags that cannot be lost not erased.
Goal is to be able to do a MR from main to release again, without collisions, "asking for rebases" and so. I don't mind if I have to put some "Fix" commits  (called F) in between to do it, somehow, like
main:    (...) - A-B-C-D-E-F-G
release: (...) - A-F1-F2-B-C-D-E-F-G


without using rebase nor resets ... but this in fact is how I would remedy the situation.

git revert is the answer here

If you cannot rebase or change the history of the release branch, the best solution is revert
//on branch 'release'
git revert S

This will remove the changes introduced by S.  Further merges from main should not cause any merge conflicts. Since you are immediately reverting S on the next commit, the revert will not cause any conflicts either.
release: (...)-A-S-revert(S) // effectively as S had not been added to release branch


Great suggestion!
